# Improve Ansible Performance

Tags: performance, ansible

I'm attempting to improve the performance for ansible playbooks. I have a test playbook as follows:

```yaml
---
- name: Test
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Creating an empty file
      file:
        path: /tmp/hello
        state: touch

    - name: Test
      command: "echo 'Hello, World!' >> /tmp/hello"
      with_sequence: start=1 end=500
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Running this takes a whopping 57 seconds. Comparing to a bash script doing the same thing:

*test.sh*

```sh
#!/bin/bash
touch /tmp/hello
for i in {1..500}
do
  sh /home/admin/hello.sh
  echo "This is iteration $i"
done
```

*hello.sh*

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello, World!" >> /tmp/hello
```

That takes ~1.5 seconds to run.

I have already made some changes to `ansible.cfg` file

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=18000s -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey
control_path = %(directory)s/ansible-ssh-%%h-%%p-%%r
pipelining = True
```

Is there anything else I can do to improve this abysmal performance?

Answer (score 4):

With your code, ansible will connect 500 times to the host to run a command. You could create your desired file first, and then upload it to the host.

### playbook.yml

```yaml
---
- name: Test
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: create 'hello' file
      ansible.builtin.template:
        src: "../templates/hello.j2"
        dest: "/tmp/hello"
```

### hello.j2

```
{% for i in range(500) %}
Hello, World!
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I see. That helps this particular case, but I'm looking for a more general solution. We have a lot of ansible playbooks, and I'm trying to find a way to optimise them, or to understand why they are so slow. The purpose of the playbook described in my question is purely for the purposes of benchmarking

Comment: @GraemeSeaman then you'll have to give us a more concrete example, possibly in a new question. As stated, by this answer, the issue is that you will have to have deal with the connection overhead, in Ansible. What you can do, here is to build your loop in the command: `shell: "for i in {1..500}; do echo 'Hello, World!' >> /tmp/hello; done"`